# Recursive factorial output

Tags: vb.net, recursion, factorial

I'm trying to write a recursive function through a vb console application that will output the factorial or a number between 1 and 10. I get a System.StackOverflowException when I run it. Can anyone help explain what I've done wrong?

```
Module Module1
Dim Number As Byte
Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Write a number from 1-10")
    Number = Console.ReadLine()

    FactorialCalc()

End Sub
Function FactorialCalc()

    Dim Counter As Byte

    Dim A As Byte
    ' Dim Factorial As Integer

    Do
        If Number < 1 Or Number > 10 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Please select a number from 1-10")
        End If

    Loop Until Number >= 1 And Number <= 10

    A = Number

    Do
        FactorialCalc = Number * FactorialCalc(Number - 1)
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop Until Counter = A + 1

    Console.WriteLine(FactorialCalc.value)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Recursion or loop? You should be using both of them in a factorial program.

Comment: How big do you think a byte is?

Answer (score 1):

A factorial program shouldn't be all this long. All you need is:

```
Module Module1
    Dim Number As Integer

    Sub Main()
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Write a number from 1-10")
            Number = Console.ReadLine()
        Loop Until Number >= 1 And Number <= 10

        Dim Result = FactorialCalc()

        Console.WriteLine(Result)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Function FactorialCalc(num as Integer) As Integer
        Return num * If(num > 2, FactorialCalc(num - 1), 2)
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

your recursive call to FactorialCalc(Number - 1) is going to keep getting called endlessly, there by exhausting your stack space. The condition to break out of the recursion is after your recursive call and so control never reaches the point beyond the call to the recursive function and keeps calling it over and over again.